# Mortal terror has no blood potency resistance?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem-2e

Mortal Terror is the only power I've read from the Nightmare discipline that does not have Blood Potency added for the victim. Is that an oversight or true?

Answer (score 6):

### Not an Oversight

My guess is that it's not an oversight. Notice that all the other Nightmare powers are vs. tests (opposed rolls).

For example, *The Grand Delusion:*

> **Dice  Pool:**  Manipulation  +  Empathy  +  Nightmare  vs.  Composure + Blood Potency

Whereas, *Mortal Terror* is *not* an opposed roll. Composure functions as a penalty to the dice roll.

> **Dice Pool:** Presence + Intimidation + Nightmare – victim’s Composure

This is similar to how Defense works in the nWoD system, a penalty on the dice roll from the lowest of your Wits or Dex. Notice that you (almost?) never see two stats combined as a penalty to a die roll. That'd result in rolls that are, the majority of the time, reduced to a Chance Die.

### You've already affected them

Note also that *Mortal Terror* requires that you have already given them Conditions from Disciplines that *do* require a test vs. Blood Potency.

> **Condition:**  The  vampire  needs  to  have  inflicted  the  Frightened or Delusional Conditions on her victim.

Comment: most of the time even with dice penalties the blood potency also plays a roll thpough (at least for the other splats). sometimes its really confusing why they did so or so.